# Google Cloud API Duplicate file copied in APK com/google/cloud/project.properties

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

This is my build.gradle(app) file, when I try to Sync this there are 8 warning showing up and when I try to run this application there are few warnings and a error saying there is a `Duplicate file Exception`.

I'm trying to implement Google cloud Datastore in my android Application

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appspot.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    packagingOptions {

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-datastore', version: '+'
}
```

Upon hitting Sync Now, I get the following Warnings:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 1.791 secs
Information:0 errors
Information:8 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

And this is the error that I see when I try to run my application:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20160810 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK com/google/cloud/project.properties
    File1: C:\Users\mbhar\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-core\1.0.0-rc2\aadb514fb6e48585c5fb1b2bbca1a84db38bdd6f\google-cloud-core-1.0.0-rc2.jar
    File2: C:\Users\mbhar\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-core-http\1.0.0-rc2\fe5de264bf8a3357d69f0643d31eca582cee119c\google-cloud-core-http-1.0.0-rc2.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.487 secs
Information:1 error
Information:4 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Cloud endpoints is the dependency you want, right? Not the whole datastore api?

Comment: Actually I want to use the following imports:
`import java.util.ArrayList;`
and want these 3 dependencies:
`google-cloud-core`
`google-cloud-core-http`
`google-cloud-datastore`

Comment: Again, endpoints is how you should interact with the datastore API. I think the dependency you have is for Java servers, not Android apps.

Comment: Okay. So, how can I use Cloud endpoints to interact with my Android application. I want to access the data that is already present in my Datastore. The data in my Datastore is from a Web application. Sorry, I'm totally new to Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding those duplicates should get rid of that error

```
compile('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:1.0.0-rc2') {
    exclude group: 'org.json'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

**BUT** Android has deprecated Apache HTTP Components from the SDK as of Android 6.

So, I really think you should [setup Endpoints](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints) because

> Google Cloud Endpoints [provides] automated Java object marshalling/unmarshalling to JSON, generation of strongly-typed client libraries that can be called from your Android app, built-in authentication support and so on.

I think that link deploys a Java backend, but I have used this with a Python App Engine app, just can't remember how it worked.